# How to put my facebook messenger extension into messenger offered extension app list

Tags: facebook, messenger

I sent into facebook app review my messenger extension few days ago, and it passed. Before i started to develop this messenger extension i belived that it will appear in messenger at the installed extension list. As you see it is missing from this list. Can you explain how can i approve by facebook my extension to get there.? Is it achievable or not?

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eatYm.png)